# Permanent disabling of a button after it is pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created this script to disable a button permanently after it's pressed, but the issue is that previously we disabled it and when we exited the game test, it didn't remain disabled. Now, it remains permanently disabled, but I want it to be disabled only after the first press.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonOff : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static bool buttonDisabled = false;
    private Button button;
    private bool buttonClicked = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        button = GetComponent<Button>();
        button.onClick.AddListener(DisableButtonOnClick);

        
        if (buttonDisabled)
        {
            button.interactable = false;
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        
        int buttonDisabledValue = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("ButtonDisabled", 0);
        buttonDisabled = buttonDisabledValue == 1;

        
        
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("ButtonDisabled", buttonDisabled ? 1 : 0);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    private void DisableButtonOnClick()
    {
        
            buttonDisabled = true;
            button.interactable = false;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You said _"it didn't remain disabled."_ and _"Now, it remains permanently disabled"_, is it disabled or not?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the issue lies in how you handle the buttonDisabled variable and its initialization. Right now, you are initializing buttonDisabled to `false`, which means every time the game starts, it will start with the button being interactable. But when you set buttonDisabled to true after the first press, it will persist across game sessions because you save it to PlayerPrefs.

To fix this, you should change the initialization of buttonDisabled to read from PlayerPrefs only once during the Start method. This way, the buttonDisabled will be set based on whether the button was previously clicked or not, and it won't reset to `false` every time the game starts.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonOff : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static bool buttonDisabled = false;
    private Button button;
    private bool buttonClicked = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        button = GetComponent<Button>();
        button.onClick.AddListener(DisableButtonOnClick);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        int buttonDisabledValue = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("ButtonDisabled", 0);
        buttonDisabled = buttonDisabledValue == 1;

        if (buttonDisabled)
        {
            button.interactable = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("ButtonDisabled", buttonDisabled ? 1 : 0);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    private void DisableButtonOnClick()
    {
        if (!buttonClicked)
        {
            buttonClicked = true;
            buttonDisabled = true;
            button.interactable = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you wrote to your playerprefs => it is already stored there to be disabled permanently!

You will have to reset this e.g. using a `[ContextMenu]`

```
public class ButtonOff : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    [ContextMenu("Reset Button")]
    private void ResetButton()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("ButtonDisabled");
    }
}
```

You call this in the Inspector via the context menu of the according component.

Also: Is there a good reason why this should be using a `static`? I would probably expect this to be working for multiple buttons using different keys so they can be locked individually.

Also you should then handle `if(buttonDisabled)` **after** having read it from the playerprefs!